# D3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm trying to map the per-capita crime rates in Florida by county using D3.

I have my crime data merged with my Florida geojson data. All data is located in *'data/florida.geojson'*.

```
        d3.json("data/florida.geojson", function (json) {

            console.log(json.features);

            console.log(parseFloat(json.features[0].values.Arrests_1998));

            svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    var value = parseFloat(d.values.Arrests_1998); // ERROR HERE!
                    if (value) {
                        return ("rgb(" + color(value) + ",0,0)");
                    } else {
                        return "#ccc";
                    }
                })
                .style("stroke", "#fff");
```

I have two `console.log()` lines written in the code for debugging. From the console, I can see that `json.features[0].values.Arrests_1998` does have a value (0.032).

[image]

The object that is bound to the path elements looks like this:

[image]

So when I create the 'path' elements, I'm binding each json.features object to an element. So why can't I reference it as `d.values.Arrests_1998` in my .style call?

Comment: What do you get if you simply `console.log(d)` in the `.style("fill",` function?

Comment: Firstly, it is complaining that the `values` property is undefined, not Àrrests_1998`. What you are logging is the property of the first feature object, i.e. `json.features[0]`; are you sure all other 66 feature objects, i.e. `json.feature[1]` through `json.feature[66]` really do have a `values` property?

Comment: That helped me find the problem. The issue was a missing value on an object, causing it to break. I fixed the missing value and it works perfectly now. Thanks!